# Do HTC components work in Safari?

Tags: html, safari, html-components

Do HTML components or “HTC” work in Safari?

Answer (score 2):

No.

They only work in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

HTML components are an extension to HTML created by Microsoft and are only supported by Internet Explorer